# Projection onto a Line: why must the projection be a multiple of the vector $a$?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, projection

In the book: Linear Algebra and its application -Gilbert Strang-, when the projection $p$ of vector $b$ onto vector $a$ is explained, this is said:

We want to find the projection point $p$. This point must be some multiple $p= \hat{x}a $ of the given vector $a$, every point on the line is a multiple of $a$.

Reference image:

[image]

Why must the projection $p$ be a multiple of the vector $a$?

Comment: Is he really saying that a *point* is a multiple of a *vector*? How ugly... Anyway, isn't it clear from the figure? They're parallel (by definition), so they must be multiples.

Comment: Because p is collinear with a, or in other words, is pointing in the same direction as a. This is simply by construction. So the vector p has to be a scalar multiple of the vector a. A special case would be where p = a (if your dotted line were to intersect right where the arrowhead of a ends)

Comment: so why must p and a be linearly dependent vectors?